# Get base64 string from a big StorageFile and store it in another StorageFile

Tags: vb.net, uwp

i have a >4 GB StorageFile and i want to convert it to a base64 string and store the string in another StorageFile.

I have IBuffer to read the file:

```
Dim tempFolder As StorageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder   
Dim ftemp As StorageFile = Await tempFolder.TryGetItemAsync(filename)
Dim ibuf As IBuffer = Await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(ftemp)
Dim b64list As New List(Of String)
Dim b64string As String = String.Empty
Dim countins As Long = 0
Dim byt As Byte() = {}

If ibuf.Length > 500000000 Then

While ibuf.Length - countins > 500000000
byt = ibuf.ToArray(countins, 500000000) 'when countins exceeds 2 Gb, i get overflowexception: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow
Dim b1 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(byt, 0, 500000000)
b64list.Add(b1)
countins = countins + 500000000
End While

byt = ibuf.ToArray(countins, ibuf.Length - countins)
Dim b2 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(byt, countins, ibuf.Length - countins)
b64list.Add(b2)

else

b64string = Convert.ToBase64String(ibuf.ToArray())

End If
```

Because the limits of the size of the Byte() object is about 2Gb, i tried to split the bytes stored in the buffer array in other smaller bytes and convert it in a base64 string, then add the string in a list of string and write the base64 string in the file by the list of string. The problem is when the offset of bytes to read and convert exceeds 2Gb of size (please, see the comments in the code!).

is there a way to read the bytes from 2 gb to up contained in the ibuffer?

Thank you very much!

**Edit:**
The solution of Nico Zhu is perfect! Thank you very much.
That's just what i was looking for. 
I tried with files of about 6 GB and it seems to work perfectly, occupying an average of 7 GB of ram to finish the operation. For the x86 version i set a limit of 2 Gb for the files to open, it is not a problem.

I paste my vb.net code version for the vb.net community (tested up to 6Gb):

```
Dim BufferList As List(Of IBuffer) = New List(Of IBuffer)()
Dim lclFolder As StorageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder   
Dim ftemp As StorageFile = Await lclFolder.TryGetItemAsync(filename)

Dim stredam = Await ftemp.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)
Dim size As ULong = stredam.Size
Dim splLength As UInteger = 1024 * 1024 * 128
Dim splCount = size / splLength
Dim res As IBuffer = Nothing

If size < splLength Then
res = Await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(ftemp.generalfileselectedsmp)

Else

Dim splitCount = size / splLength

For i As Integer = 0 To CInt(splitCount) - 1
Dim postition = i * splLength

Using inputStream = stredam.GetInputStreamAt(CULng(postition))

Using dataReader = New Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(inputStream)
Dim numBytesLoaded As UInteger = Await dataReader.LoadAsync(splLength)
Dim buffder = dataReader.ReadBuffer(numBytesLoaded)
BufferList.Add(buffder)
End Using

End Using
Next

Dim leftLength = size Mod splLength

Using inputstream As IInputStream = stredam.GetInputStreamAt(splitCount * splLength)

Using dataReader As New DataReader(inputstream)
Dim numBytesLoaded As UInteger = Await dataReader.LoadAsync(CUInt(leftLength))
Dim leftBuffer = dataReader.ReadBuffer(numBytesLoaded)
BufferList.Add(leftBuffer)
End Using

End Using

Dim nnb As Long = 0

Dim tempFolder As StorageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder
Dim ftempdest As StorageFile = Await tempFolder.CreateFileAsync("tmpxencrxx0212", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)

For Each ibb As IBuffer In BufferList
If ibb.Length > 0 Then

Await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(ftempdest, Convert.ToBase64String(ibb.ToArray()))

nnb = nnb + 1
End If
Next
```

Comment: Why would you need a list? Just read a chunk of data that is a multiple of 8 bytes long, convert it to base-64 and write the result to the output file. There's no need to store the results before writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to read the bytes from 2 gb to up contained in the ibuffer?

For your requirement, we suggest you cut the big file into slices and use IBuffer list to store each slip. Please note you need set the app target platform to x64 that has enough memory to store such buffers.

```
private List<IBuffer> BufferList = new List<IBuffer>();

var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
picker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
picker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".zip");

Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();
var stredam = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
ulong size = stredam.Size;
uint splLength = 1024 * 1024 * 128;
var splCount = size / splLength;

if (size < splLength)
{
  var res = FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(sampleFile);
}
else
{
    var splitCount = size / splLength;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)splitCount; i++)
    {
        var postition = i * splLength;
        using (var inputStream = stredam.GetInputStreamAt((ulong)postition))
        {
            using (var dataReader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(inputStream))
            {
                uint numBytesLoaded = await dataReader.LoadAsync(splLength);
                var buffder = dataReader.ReadBuffer(numBytesLoaded);
                BufferList.Add(buffder);
            }
        }


    }
    var leftLength = size % splLength;
    using (var inputStream = stredam.GetInputStreamAt(splitCount * splLength))
    {
        using (var dataReader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(inputStream))
        {
            uint numBytesLoaded = await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)leftLength);
            var leftBuffer = dataReader.ReadBuffer(numBytesLoaded);
            BufferList.Add(leftBuffer);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect solution, it was what i was looking for.